# Replacing a call to sleep when waiting on an NSStream response

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstream

I made an application which uses `NSStream` to etablish a connection to a telnet server.
When the connection is made, I send a first command. Then I use `sleep(1);` to make my application wait. Then the second command is sent.

The problem is that the entire GUI is stuck during the `sleep()`. I know that it's not the "perfect" way to make a "pause" and I'd like to learn how to this properly. I heard good things about `NSTimer` but I'd like to have a concrete and "easy" way of using it, to simply replace my poor use of `sleep()`.

Comment: How are you making the connection?

Comment: Not only will it make your GUI unresponsive, it can(and probably eventually will) crash your GUI.  Never perform sleeps on the main thread in Cocoa(doubly so for Cocoa touch)

Comment: @user: On iOS, it's not a crash, it's the system killing your app because it's unresponsive. OS X doesn't have a watchdog timer like iOS does, and apps can be stalled or sleeping indefinitely. That said, you're right that one should not use `sleep()`, doubly so on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to register some kind of callback with whatever procedure you're using to establish the connection. Just let your code wait for that callback without doing anything at all.

In this case, using `NSStream`, you need to [schedule the stream on the run loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/PollingVersusRunloop.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002275-CJBEDDBG):

```
[stream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                  forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

The run loop is the construct that processes events for your application. When you use `sleep()`, it is stopped, and your GUI can't do anything. By adding the stream as input to the run loop, you allow them both to continue to work.

You also must set a delegate object (`[stream setDelegate:self];`, e.g.) which will [recieve notifications when](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/ReadingInputStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002273-1001882) the stream has something to report. That delegate must implement `stream:handleEvent:`, which will be called with a reference to the stream and a code indicating what happened.

Comment: So easy that I didn't think about it! I can wait the ">" char in the inputstream before sending my next command in the outputstream! With this way I'll have the "perfect" wait time! Thanks for your light! :)